# gnuplot: Show a summary of a subset of some time indexed data

Tags: gnuplot

Lets say you have a dat file that has a month worth of some data you want to graph... is there a way to tell gnuplot to only graph the last weeks worth and just ignore everything before that?

Comment: Yes, use `set timefmt`, `set xdata time` and `set xrange`. If you need more specific help, you need to be more specific in you question.

Comment: You could `set xrange` to some specific dates... like ["Aug 08 2013":"Aug 14 2013"] or whatever but that doesn't mean "the last week" it means "these explicit dates"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `time` function to get the system time, subtract one week (in seconds) from that and then format the time according to your requirements for `set xrange`:

```
sys_time = time(0)
set xdata time
set timefmt '%b %d %Y' # according to the comment
set xdata time
set xrange[strftime('%b %d %Y', sys_time - 7*24*60*60): strftime('%b %d %Y', sys_time)]
....
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, when did they add the `time` command?  I don't have it with gnuplot 4.4 ... For a workaround, you could do a `strftime(system("date +%Y-%m-%d"),"%Y-%m-%d"))` or something similar...

Comment: Just checked it out.  Installed gnuplot 4.6 on my laptop and it seems to be there.  Good find.

Comment: @mgilson For my stuff I always use the development version, the things I post here are also tested with the 4.6 version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  See the `every` keyword description on page 78 of the gnuplot manual:

http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.6/gnuplot.pdf

E.g.

```
plot "data.txt" every ::a:A:b:B
```

should plot data points `a` through `b` in data blocks `A` through `B`.